# Change "show desktop" shortcut in macOS and Windows

Tags: windows-10, mac, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using one Windows 10 and one Mac laptops and I want to make them consistent in the shortcut key to show desktop. Right now, the key in Mac is `F11` and in PC it is `Win+D`. Is there a way to change one of them to the other so that I can use the same shortcut when using any laptop? This would make my life much easier and save me time. I checked the options for Mac and looks like there is no `Cmd+D` option -- given macOS `Cmd` corresponds to the `Win` key, this shortcut would have been useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cmd key in macOS is used in a fashion akin to Control in Windows -- common shortcuts like Undo, Cut, Copy and Paste are mapped to Cmd+Z, Cmd+X, Cmd+C, Cmd+V, etc. The Cmd+D shortcut is frequently used by web browsers for the Add Bookmark command, and in the Finder for Duplicate, so remapping it to a system-wide shortcut may not be a great idea.

That's not to say it isn't possible, though! You can set this as a shortcut in the Keyboard preferences pane -- switch to the Shortcuts tab, click "Mission Control", then double-click the line for "Show Desktop" and type the shortcut you'd like to use. Some *really* bad shortcuts (like unmodified letters or numbers) can't be selected, but there are few other requirements.

[image: Screenshot of the Keyboard preferences pane with "Show Desktop" remapped to Cmd+D]

I'm not aware of any similarly easy way to remap Win+key shortcuts in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Both operating systems you have specified have software available on the 'net called keyboard remapping software. As this is not the Software Recommendations SE, I won't specify, but the variety of choices is quite large.

There is a near-duplicate of this question, although the OP requests no third-party software. Your question did not have this limitation, hence the suggestion for using keyboard remapping software.

Alternatively, hot-key programs can accomplish a similar result. Mapping/setting the hot key for F11 to Win-D might be simpler and/or the program you select with that focus may have less overhead.